# how to capture the recaptcha Response in jmeter from a get request

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, recaptcha, jmeter-5.0, grecaptcha

I am having a get request containing reCaptcha on submitting a contact form with a Post request.
And when making scripts for Performance testing, there in response, reCaptcha value, which is needed in the post request.
Can anyone help me out with that?

Answer (score 0):

CAPTCHA is the acronym for "Completely Automated Public Turing test to tell Computers and Humans Apart" so this is exactly what it is used for: make automation very hard or even impossible in order to protect against bots and [DDoS attacks](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ddos/what-is-a-ddos-attack/).

Theoretically you could use [machine vision](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d52/tutorial_java_dev_intro.html) combined with [machine learning](https://github.com/eclipse/deeplearning4j) in [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) using [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) but it will consume really a lot of CPU and RAM even for 1 user and won't guarantee 100% success.

So if reCaptcha isn't your primary functional or performance test target instead of trying to bypass it I would recommend asking your developers or devops to disable it for the duration of the performance test as you need to focus solely on your application, all 3rd-party content and integration should be switched off or moved out of the testing scope by any other means.

Comment: Its in the requirement, according to it, at the captcha, need to check the load time, functionality, in that case, need to identify that it is a bot or human, submission for 5-sec duration.
Any solution as its having reCaptcha V3, used in the site.

Comment: Can anyone help me

Comment: can u help me with this